# how to switch between Http and Https in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, http, ssl, https, security

i want to apply SSL security on few pages of my website. Do you have any idea for it?
Can you tell me how i can switch between Https and Https? Actually the matter is i have big web application and i want to apply SSL security only for few pages. Is it possible to do so? If Yes then how? Please reply as soon as possible

I have searched on Net and found we can use encryptedUri and unencryptedUri for this but How i dont know ? Can someone explain how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using this in the past:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/http_https.aspx?q=switch+ssl+asp.net

Also here's a solution that doesn't require any 3rd party modules:
http://technicalsol.blogspot.com/2009/04/switching-between-http-to-https.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do any coding for this. Install the security certificate on your side. Most of the hosting provider will do this. Then use https in the links where ever you want https and http where ever you want http.

One thing you need to keep in mind, for pages those will be served as https should have their resources also pointed using https. example images, css etc.

example,

In hyperlinks you can give fully http or https.

For http,
http://www.example.com/examplepage.aspx 
For https,
https://www.example.com/examplepage2.aspx